# Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Seems like every time I switch to coding on a new MACcomputer I get some messages like this:

```
Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service.
```

from XF and then XF manages to deploy but then I see that there are delays or problems connecting the debugger.

Does anyone know what this means?

The message is accompanied by this:

```
2019-12-28 19:27:20.244 mlaunch[12561:2037717] Thread Pool Worker DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection: Failed to start Instruments daemon on device ???00008030-0009094A3C04802E???: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402653083 "Xcode encountered an error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not connect to the device., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001117666e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111766de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111777d0c __63-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startFirstServiceOf:unlockKeybag:]_block_invoke + 301
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001117774db __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_3 + 22
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011176915f __DTDKExecuteInSession_block_invoke_2 + 35
    5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111768593 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke_2 + 473
    6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111768391 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke + 106
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bec763d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bed3478 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 65
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bed2fe6 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 195
    10  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000110c50120 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 208
    11  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000110c27548 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 64
    12  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111768292 DTDKExecuteWithConnection + 226
    13  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111768fc9 DTDKExecuteInSession + 376
    14  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111777410 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_2 + 112
    15  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000110c4de8a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    16  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000110c4f562 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bec65f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bec763d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5becd8e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bece396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5bed66ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5c107611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5c1073fd start_wqthread + 13
), DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Xcode encountered an error}
warning MT1043: Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service.
```

Comment: According to your error message, I am not sure what problem you encounter, so can you provide some code here, and point where you have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As seen on https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3797#issuecomment-494001302

This was fixed for me as I wasn't using any entitlements.

So you can remove the Entitlement from the IOS bundle build.